# Powershell - How to group rows when using Import-CSV

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

I have a CSV file with one column, SharePoint Site URLs:

```
Site A
Site A
Site B
Site C
Site C
Site C
```

How can I group the rows so the I only have unique sites:

```
Site A
Site B
Site C
```

Comment: Use import-csv | select-object -unique parameter!